# while installing TestNg in Eclipse juno , i am getting error

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testing, automation, testng

while installing TestNg in Eclipse juno , i am getting error

**error message**

Missing requirement: TestNG Eclipse Support 7.2.0.202005051752 (org.testng.eclipse 7.2.0.202005051752) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.10.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: TestNG 7.2.0.202005051752 (org.testng.eclipse.feature.group 7.2.0.202005051752)
    To: org.testng.eclipse [7.2.0.202005051752]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing requirement message is saying that at least version 3.10.0 of the `org.eclipse.jdt.launching` plug-in is required to install that build of testng.

Eclipse Juno only had version 3.6.100 or 3.6.101 of that plug-in so it is not possible to install this in Juno. Eclipse Juno is now 8 years and 13 releases old.

If you want to run the current testng release you need to be running the current Eclipse (2020-03, soon to be 2020-06).